# Python: return letters not in string

Tags: python, string, contains

I was wondering if there was a method or way to return letters not in a string.

Meaning: Let's say I have the word "testing". `"ing" in "testing"` returns true but I want to return the letters in `"testing"` that are `NOT in "ing"`   --- `"test"`

My plan was to go in this direction: But clearly it's wrong and I've been stuck on this for a while.

```
str = "testing"

cmpr = "ing"

    if cmpr in str
      return *letters* not cmpr in string

output = "test"
```

*EDIT* Better example: (where the letters do not appear in a row)

str = "testing"

cmpr = "tet"

str.replace(cmpr, '', 1) ----> I want it to return "sing" but it still returns "testing"

Can someone please help me solve this?

Comment: For example "sing" is converted "s"?

Comment: What if you have `cmpr = 'ab'` and `str = 'ababac'`? Do you want `'abac'`, `'ac'`, `'c'`, or something else? (Also, don't name your strings `str`, or when you try to call `str(something)`, you'll get a weird TypeError.)

Comment: in your case I'd want abac

Comment: @user2456977 Then you'd want `str.replace(cmpr, '', 1)` to only replace the first occurrence.

Comment: "testing" --- "tet" ---> I want it to return "sing" but the replace method doesn't do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
str = "ababac"
cmpr = "ab"

for chr in cmpr:
    if chr in str:
        str = str.replace(chr,'',1)
print str
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
str.replace(cmpr,'')
```

Comment: "testing" --- "tet" ---> I want it to return "sing" it still returns "testing"

Answer (score 0):

Well, if testing is 7 characters long..

0|1|2|3|4|5|6|

T|E|S|T|I|N|G|

You can PRINT the first 6 characters with:

```
print my_string[0:6]
```

So I think you could print by the following:(?)

```
return my_string(0:6)
```

I don't have Python up and running to test this. It's just where I would start.

To clarify, you could say

```
return testing(0:3)
```

So the output should be:

```
test
```